# How can I save a commit from branch A into branch B?

Tags: git

I have 3 different branches: production, development and staging. We are currently using the development branch to  merge our code.  However,  in the last commit in development branch the build has failed. The successfully build is in the previous commit.  How can I store the development commit that was successfully build into the staging branch?

This is what I'm trying to do:

1. git checkout staging
2. git checkout -b
   staging-with-successfully-commit-from-development-branch
3. git cherry-pick my-hash-commit

But when I do that I can't install the dependencies because I don't have a package.json.
Is there another way of doing that?

Comment: Do you mean you want the "staging" branch to stem from the last good commit from "development" branch?

Comment: Yes. I just need to save it (the good commit) inside the staging branch

Comment: I think you can merge good commit into staging. `git checkout staging && git merge  my-hash-commit`. But then to merge into development you'll still have to incorporate the last bad commit, thus either wait for development to be fixed by someone else before merging into it, or fix yourself in your staging branch before merging into development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to point your **staging** branch to the "last good commit". In that case:

First make sure you have no pending changes that you want to keep. Save them in a `commit` or `stash`. Then:

```
git checkout staging
git reset --hard <the-good-commit>
git push
```

This means:

- `git checkout staging`: go to the **staging** branch
- `git reset --hard <the-good-commit>`: make the **staging** branch point to . The `--hard` option indicates that you want all your current files to be changed as well to have the exact contents of . If you had any uncommitted changes, they will be lost forever. Depending on your workflow you can also use `git merge` or `git rebase`.
- `git push`: push the new version of the release branch to the remote server.